# Getting picklist values for record type through REST API

Tags: rest-api

My org has two record types on the `Event` sobject. There is one field (of type picklist) that has different values for each layout. I need to get the unique fields for one record type.

When I call the describe function on the `Event` object it just gives me all picklist values.

When I call the describe layout function (`/services/data/vXXX/sobjects/Event/describe/layouts`) it returns a list of `recordTypeMappings` and the correct record types are there, but for each record type there is a prop `picklistsForRecordType` which is strangely empty. Even though in the SF setup there are multiple picklists that should seemingly show up there.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the picklist values for a recordType by [ui-api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_picklist_values_collection.htm) . you need to replace the url with

```
/services/data/v48.0/ui-api/object-info/{objectAPIName}/picklist-values/{recordTypeID}
```

Comment: I think you have asked same Question twice. The answer is already give by @sfdcfox https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/314120/56744 and it has some more info on your use case